# Display a WebP image in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webp

I am writing an image viewer. Very simple. Just displays images from files. But whenever I try Image.FromFile and pass in a WebP file, it blows up with an 'Out of Memory' error.

Clearly, WebP files are not supported. So clearly, I need to load the WebP file somehow and decode it and translate it into an Image or Bitmap object.

But I can't seem to find any way to do that. Isn't there some simple library I can use that will do this?

I found a Nuget package called Imazen.WebP and some sample code. But that code blows up, too when decoding:

System.DllNotFoundException
HResult=0x80131524
Message=Unable to load DLL 'libwebp': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
Source=Imazen.WebP

There is some kind of dependency I must be missing, but I don't really know anything about the WebP format, I just have a file on my hard drive and want to view it. Windows Explorer has no problem previewing it or showing a thumbnail in Windows Explorer. And Windows Photo View can view it. So I must have something on my machine that can decode these images.

So how do I do it in C#?

TIA

Comment: The NuGet is just a wrapper over native `libwebp.dll`. You must also have the native dll in the same folder from where you are executing your program. The [github page](https://github.com/imazen/libwebp-net#windows-builds-of-libwebp-052-can-be-found-here) mentions where to find the native dll.

Comment: Also you can use os image viewer if your app got exception by Proccess.Start